# ruby dynamic method passing a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I pass a value to a dynamic method name that's called on a rails model?

```
@model.send(dynamic_method_name.to_sym,123)
```

This gives the error:

```
 wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

If I were to use the same method like this though:

```
 @model.post_id = 123
```

then it works.

So there is a "setter" method for the method post_id (and therefore the dynamic method name).

How do I pass a value to this setter when the method is dynamic?

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the "=" to your dynamic_method_name. In ruby, `:post_id` is the name of the getter, and `:post_id=` is the name of the setter. The `.to_sym` isn't strictly necessary so you can do this:

```
@model.send("#{dynamic_method_name}=", 123)
```